# array_push the first key of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having a hard time adding a piece to an array in an if statement while using `array_push`. If I try to change `$arr` to `$arr[0]`, then I get an error :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

PHP:

```
$data = array('test' => 'value');
if(!empty($_POST['stuff'])){
        $arr = array('test2' => array(array('test3' => 'value')));
        array_push($data, $arr);
      }
$data_string = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

this is what's currently happening:

```
{
    "test": "value",
    "0": {
        "test2": [{
            "test3": "value"
            }]
         }

}
```

This is what I want to happen:

```
{
    "test": "value",
    "test2": [{
            "test3": "value"
            }]
}
```

Comment: You are showing us the result of `json_encode` correct?

Comment: Yes sorry I'll add that to the code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**array_merge()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead :

```
$data = array_merge($data,$arr);
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/161159)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I get for going off of 3 hours of sleep!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `array_push`, you can't control associative keys:

```
$data['test2'] = array(array('test3' => 'value'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_push` is for indexed arrays. You are using an associative array and so you simply need to do

```
$data = array('test' => 'value');
if(!empty($_POST['stuff'])){
    $data['test2'] = array(array('test3' => 'value')));
}
```